# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in nested loop

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

Need some help.I have been doing some basic pattern printing using arrays.I got stuck on how to manipulate the indices so as to get the desired pattern ,as you can see in the given code.I was wondering whether I could have some beginner's advice....

```
/*2 6 12 20 30 42
 * 4 6 8 10 12
 * 2 2 2 2
 * 0 0 0
 * 0 0
 * 0
 * 
 */
```

Here's the code:

```
public class pat {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int a[] = {2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42};

        for(int x = 0; x <= 5; x++) {
            int c[]={};
            for(int y = 5; y >= x; y--) {
                c[y]=a[y]-a[y-1];
                System.out.print(c[y]);
            }
            System.out.println();}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should initialize the `c` array to an array with size of `x`.

  `int c[] = new int[x];`
- There's a problem in the nested loop, as well. When `x = 0`, on the last step in the nested loop (when `y = x`) `y-1` is evaluated to `-1` and that's why you're receiving an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`
- If I were you, I would define a `previous` array, which would serve as a copy of the last evaluated array of numbers.

A possible solution:

```
int a[] = { 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42 };

int[] previous = a;
for (int x = a.length - 1; x > 0; x--) {
    int c[] = new int[x];
    for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
        c[y] = previous[y + 1] - previous[y];
        System.out.print(c[y] + " ");
    }
    previous = c;
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: It's still giving the same error.Could you possibly look at whole code please?

Answer (score 1):

Well your c[] array initialization is wrong:

```
int c[]={};
```

this will create an array of size 0;

I believe what you want to do is this:

```
int c[] = new int[6];
```

Also in the last iteration of `for(int y=5;y>=x;y--)` you will get -1 in `a[y-1]` so I would change the condition to `int y=5;y>x;y--`

Comment: @user2511145 The size needs to be 6!

Comment: Actually I reviewed the code and where I got it wrong was the part int the second nested for.I have to switch the new value with the old values of array 'a';